# How to delete files matching specific character placement?

Tags: bash, filesystems

I'm trying to delete files with names that contain certain digits in specific placement. Using bash and text file that contains those specific digits.

I have a single directory with files in the following naming convention: 2019-08-06-11-35-13_2091232924_4569.mp3

I have a text file containing area codes that I'd like to match and delete.  One of those area codes is 209.  Reading from the right of the filename is always consistent.  So I'd like to match characters 17, 18, 19 from the right, against the text file and then delete those files using bash.  I've tried plain wildcard matching but it will delete files with those digits in other positions.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: for f in $(cat areacodes.txt) ; do rm ????-??-??-??-??-??_"$f"??????_????* done

Comment: @Barmar got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `?` wildcard, which matches any single character.

```
rm ????-??-??-??-??-??_209???????_????.mp3
```

However, it appears that all the wild characters are digits, so you could use `[0-9]` instead of `?` and be safer.

```
rm [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_209[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].mp3
```

If you're getting the area code from a file, you can replace `209` in the pattern with the variable that you assigned from the file.

```
rm ????-??-??-??-??-??_"$code"??????_????.mp3
```

Comment: With this I'm getting: bash removefiles.sh
rm: ????-??-??-??-??-??_209??????_????*: No such file or directory
rm: ????-??-??-??-??-??_213??????_????*: No such file or directory

Comment: for f in $(cat areacodes.txt) ; do
  rm ????-??-??-??-??-??_"$f"??????_????*
done

Comment: I mistyped the number of `?` after `209`

Comment: Aha, I should have caught that too.  This works great!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something with `xargs`:

```sh
xargs -n1 <input.txt sh -c 'rm *_$1*_*.mp3' {}
```